# Shell Script UNIX with prompt

Tags: macos, shell, unix

i need some help with a shell script.
I want to start a shell witch is asking for some informations.
This should be saved into variables and after entering the informations it should be written in a file.

Something like that:

> call shell script
>
> > "*tell me your name*" 
> >     John

After this it should write in a file "his name is John"

I know it is a very stupid example, but if i know how to handle this i can adapt this in my special use-case.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Whats your name? "
read name
echo $name > name.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit cleaner to have the `read` command print the prompt, using its `-p` option:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Tell me your name: " name
echo "His name is $name" >name.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo` to print, `read` to read input.

```
echo -n "Tell me your name: "
read name
echo "Your name is $name."
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Tell me your name?"
read name
echo "His name is $name" > name.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to append to exiting file**

1. echo -n "Tell me your name: "
2. read name 
3. echo $name >> fileName.txt